# How to use CSS selector to eliminate element if it contains specific type of child element

Tags: html, css

Let me give an example to clarify my question.

Assume I have a table like below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <th>header2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>elem1</td>
    <td>elem2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>elem3</td>
    <td>elem4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to show that table row containing `<td>` element is clickable, so I'm trying to change the mouse pointer cursor to hand when it hovers on `<tr>` that contains `<td>` element.

I can do that by setting the style like below:

```
table tr:not(:first-child) {cursor:pointer;}
```

The first child of a table is normally the `<tr>` that contains `<th>`.

Here comes the question, how to write the css style to eliminate `<tr>` that contains `<th>` as direct child with more intuitive way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `thead` and `tbody` element, and then use CSS to only target the rows in the `tbody`:

```css
table tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>elem1</td>
      <td>elem2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>elem3</td>
      <td>elem4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

`tr td {cursor: pointer}` will do just fine:

```css
tr td {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header1
    <th>header2
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>elem1
    <td>elem2
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>elem3
    <td>elem4
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or just `td {cursor: pointer}` is fine too.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that I modify td one by one but not tr. Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to your editable tr:

```css
tr.editable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table> 
   <tr>
     <th>header1</th>
     <th>header2</th>
   </tr> 
   <tr class="editable">
     <td>elem1</td>
     <td>elem2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="editable">
     <td>elem3</td>
     <td>elem4</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use CSS pseudo-class:

It will select from 2nd to last row in your table.

```css
table tr:nth-child(n+2) {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table> 
   <tr>
     <th>header1</th>
     <th>header2</th>
   </tr> 
   <tr class="editable">
     <td>elem1</td>
     <td>elem2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="editable">
     <td>elem3</td>
     <td>elem4</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but it might not be a good idea to couple CSS style with the element appeared sequence.

Answer (score -3):

You could simply refer to all `tr` that have as their child `<td>` it will automatically omit the  `tr` with `<th>` tags

```
 table tr td {
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation when answering a question.